# What tools can provide frequency-sorted lists of interesting multi-word terms in documents?

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn, nltk

I have a set of nearly half a million text documents. For each document I want to generate a list of interesting 1-, 2-, and 3-word phrases (i.e. unigrams, bigrams, and trigrams.) By interesting, I mean phrases that occur frequently in the document but relatively infrequently in the entire corpus and phrases that are not junky phrases (e.g. "such that.") Ideally, the phrases are characteristic of the contents of the document, i.e. those phrases would be helpful in word clouds. And, if there's a way to incorporate part of speech tagging to help identify meaningful phrases that would be a plus.

I'm interested to know what tools and approaches I should consider.

Here's what I am aware of:

1. Elasticsearch (maybe with the Python elasticsearch-py library). Elasticsearch has very sophisticated full-search capabilities. Elasticsearch does have a "significant terms aggregation" feature. [1],[2] And, Elasticsearch can rank using TF/IDF. [3]
2. NLTK.
3. Scikit-learn.

Aside from what tool or set of tools to use, I need to consider my approach. I imagine I'll be experimenting with different tokenizers to split my text into words, removing stop words, then building and indexing the n-grams. I may or may not want to stem words. I'll have to experiment and see. Then, for each document, I'll want to get a frequency-sorted list of n-grams and for each n-gram of each document I'll want to score the n-gram based on its frequency in the document and its frequency in the corpus and provide a scored list of n-grams for each document.

My guess is that a Python-based toolkit and approach would work well as Python has a rich set of text mining tools and the power and flexibility to let me experiment with different parts of my processing pipeline.

I'd appreciate your thoughts on how to proceed and links to similar efforts.

[1]: Elasticsearch and significant terms aggregation https://www.elastic.co/blog/significant-terms-aggregation

[2]: Tag clouds and significant term aggregation
http://www.buzzcapture.com/en/2014/04/how-to-create-tag-clouds/

[3]: Elasticsearch and TF/IDF https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#tfidf

Comment: Stack Overflow is neither a forum nor a tutorial or code-writing service. This is a Q&A site where *specific* programming questions (usually, but not always, including some code) get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also follow the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: @MattDMo The tour page has an example of "does software x work on platform y?" That's not a specific programming question in my mind. The tour also says that it's appropriate to ask about "Specific programming problems, Software algorithms, Coding techniques, [and] Software development tools." And, I'm missing your point about my expecting a forum, or a tutorial, or code writing service.

Comment: My intent with my Q is: "I've got this technical problem to solve, what tools, and algorithms have folks used to solve it?" I'm hoping for responses of the form "I've solved something similar with this set of tools and this approach." I'm certainly not asking for a tutorial or code.

Comment: You should check out the phrases in Word2Vec, it deals with MWU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you have described is actually already exists in [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/)  for Java. Also, It has a [Python interface](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/) but not sure is it mature or not.

Things like POS tagging, Stop words removal, tokenization .. etc. are really done well by stanford CoreNLP which I think is also included in NLTK.

Comment: Anyways, It is hard to answer the full question, It looks like a research project or a master thesis description.. You seems to be on the right path. But better do more effort digging online and divide your question to more depth parts.